# Adding an attribute to a class by using properties editor

Tags: visual-studio, code-generation

Visual Studio allows you to design components visually. For example, you are designing a Windows form. You change its property in the properties editor. The IDE will generate the code in a partial class in xx.designer.cs file. We can customize this behavior by changing the UITypeEditor for the properties.

The question now is: Can we extend this code generation behavior? For example, we change a setting in the property window, and then the IDE will add a .NET attribute to the class?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, that is not possible.  Sorry.  Such a thing IS possible with Eclipse, however, because it's open source.

Comment: So Eclipse allows you to add C# attributes to code from the designer UI and this is possible because it's open source?